# How to paste one picture on top of another into a defined region

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have this simple Python code that captures video from the camera and makes predictions on the emotions of the face (took it from [here](https://github.com/atulapra/Emotion-detection) in case you need to run it).

I like to put this video capture inside this frame (center is transparent) and display all. How can I do this?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# command line argument
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("--mode",help="train/display")
mode = ap.parse_args().mode

# plots accuracy and loss curves
def plot_model_history(model_history):
    """
    Plot Accuracy and Loss curves given the model_history
    """
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))
    # summarize history for accuracy
    axs[0].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['accuracy'])+1),model_history.history['accuracy'])
    axs[0].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['val_accuracy'])+1),model_history.history['val_accuracy'])
    axs[0].set_title('Model Accuracy')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Epoch')
    axs[0].set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(model_history.history['accuracy'])+1),len(model_history.history['accuracy'])/10)
    axs[0].legend(['train', 'val'], loc='best')
    # summarize history for loss
    axs[1].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['loss'])+1),model_history.history['loss'])
    axs[1].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['val_loss'])+1),model_history.history['val_loss'])
    axs[1].set_title('Model Loss')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Loss')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Epoch')
    axs[1].set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(model_history.history['loss'])+1),len(model_history.history['loss'])/10)
    axs[1].legend(['train', 'val'], loc='best')
    fig.savefig('plot.png')
    plt.show()

# Define data generators
train_dir = 'data/train'
val_dir = 'data/test'

num_train = 28709
num_val = 7178
batch_size = 64
num_epoch = 50

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(48,48),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(48,48),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

# Create the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

# If you want to train the same model or try other models, go for this
if mode == "train":
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_info = model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=num_train // batch_size,
            epochs=num_epoch,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            validation_steps=num_val // batch_size)
    plot_model_history(model_info)
    model.save_weights('model.h5')

# emotions will be displayed on your face from the webcam feed
elif mode == "display":
    model.load_weights('model.h5')

    # prevents openCL usage and unnecessary logging messages
    cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

    # dictionary which assigns each label an emotion (alphabetical order)
    emotion_dict = {0: "Angry", 1: "Disgusted", 2: "Fearful", 3: "Happy", 4: "Neutral", 5: "Sad", 6: "Surprised"}

    # start the webcam feed
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    while True:
        # Find haar cascade to draw bounding box around face
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        facecasc = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = facecasc.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y-50), (x+w, y+h+10), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            cropped_img = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48)), -1), 0)
            prediction = model.predict(cropped_img)
            maxindex = int(np.argmax(prediction))
            text = emotion_dict[maxindex]

            if ("Happy" in text) or ("Sad" in text):
                cv2.putText(frame, text, (x+20, y-60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('Video', cv2.resize(frame,(1600,960),interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello, you have to use any GUI lib like tkinter or any web interface like flask along side with the opencv

Comment: What about minimal code sample? Why not simply resizing the video frame to fit the size of the center frame, and placing it there? something like `img[y0:y1, x0:x1, :] = resized_frame` and `cv2.imshow('img', img)`. Repeat for every video frame...

Comment: Doesn't have to fit exactly within the rectangle! I can find the exact coordinates. I just need a solution rn.

Comment: (0) have the black region as left, right, top, bottom coordinates, I'll call them `x0, x1, y0, y1` (1) use `shrunk_down = cv.resize(...)` to shrink your video frames to the correct size which is `(x1-x0, y1-y0)` (2) use numpy slicing to copy the data `canvas = picture_frame.copy(); canvas[y0:y1, x0:x1] = shrunk_down` -- and feel free to ignore Lahiru's response. it completely misses the mark with the "you have to" (this problem requires none of that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Implementation of Christoph's great solution in the comments.

Step 1:
Use the paint tool to extract the coordinates of the black box region.

[image]

you can see the x,y coordinates at the bottom of your image.

Step 2:

a. resize every frame of the video to fit the black region size.
width = x1 - x0 and height = y1 - y0.

b. replace the black region pixels with the resized frames.

code:

```
import cv2

canvasImage = cv2.imread("gift.jpeg")

x0, x1 = 163, 472
y0, y1 = 73, 290

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("desk.mp4")
    
while True:
    isNextFrameAvail, frame = cap.read()
    if not isNextFrameAvail:
        break
    frame_shrunk = cv2.resize(frame, (x1 - x0, y1 - y0))
    canvasImage[y0:y1, x0:x1] = frame_shrunk
    cv2.imshow("Result", canvasImage)
    cv2.waitKey
```

Result:

[image]